# Different frequencies data

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have data for firms that look as follows and data for inflation. However, I have may companies while inflation is the same for all companies. I am wondering how I can put the same value for inflation for each company.
[image]

I hope you will be able to help. Many thanks

Comment: Could you please provide some more context? Namely, is the "inflation" column to be `CPIN1` with present values repeated depending on row `Semester` value? Or will the column be a new one appended to your `df` with one value repeated for each row?

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem by using the concat function pd.concat.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using the concat function pd.concat.